# Convert blob of data to align with structure

Tags: c, windows, networking

```
char buf[512] = { 0 };

int ret = recv(gSock, buf, 512, 0);

typedef struct _STRUCT {
    int package;
    int version;
    char string[512];
} STRUCT, *PSTRUCT;

PSTRUCT ok;

ok = (PSTRUCT)buf;
```

I am trying to accept a buffer from a socket (Code not here, but it is working). It accepts it and places it into buf. I then want to cast this buf as a structure STRUCT. I want the first 4 bytes to go into the first member, second 4 bytes into the second member, and then the remaining data to go into the last member. However this is not working like I expected. I am getting weird large numbers that are not what I am receiving.

I entered 1111111111 (10) and the results I got back were;

```
package = 825307441
version = 825307441
string = 11\n
```

I did a decimal to hex conversion on the package number and it comes back as '31313131', which is my first 4 1's. So I am not to sure why it is going from integer, to hex back to a integer. I want just exactly what sends to go into the structure.

Comment: Try printing out the `int` values in hex instead of decimal.  Then look at an ASCII-to-hex table.  You'll learn something...

Comment: I know that is what is doing. But I want to know why. I want to compare package against many different things so pakage 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc I want to compare against "1", "2", "3". Not against the converted number. And I am not printing them. I am using VS debugger I can see what they are.

Comment: You're sending a string like `"11111111..."`, right? What is the value of i after `int i; memcpy(&i, "1111", 4);`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to review the following functions:

htonl, htons, ntohl, ntohs - convert values between host and network byte order.